Can't clear an instance in vue js, using beforeunmount
I'm using a widget from the artplacer website in my script but when I leave the page the instance is still there even when I set it to null in the unmount hook.
Here is the entire script - my version of vue is 5.0.8:
<script>
import PageHeader from "@/components/PageHeader.vue";
import ImageText from "@/components/ImageText.vue";
import LikeButton from "@/components/LikeButton.vue";
import ArtpieceBuyFormModal from "@/components/modals/ArtpieceBuyFormModal.vue";
import ArtpiecesCarousel from "@/components/artpiece/ArtpiecesCarousel.vue";
//
import { HeartIcon } from "@heroicons/vue/24/outline";
//
import ArtpieceService from "@/services/artpiece.service";
import { useAuthStore } from "@/store/auth";
import { useModalStore } from "@/store/modal";
import { useCartStore } from "@/store/cart";

// import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
export default {
name: "ArtpieceDetailPage",
components: {
  PageHeader,
  ImageText,
  HeartIcon,
  LikeButton,
  ArtpieceBuyFormModal,
  ArtpiecesCarousel,
},
data() {
  return {
    carouselVisible: false,
    artist: null,
    artpiece: null,
    mainImage: null,
    defaultImage: "/img/default/profile.jpg",
    isLoading: true,

  };
},

toogleCarousel() {
  this.carouselVisible = carouselVisible;
},

async mounted() {
  console.log('Component mounted');

  this.authStore = useAuthStore();
  this.modalStore = useModalStore();
  this.cartStore = useCartStore();

  await this.fetchArtpieceInfo();
  this.authStore.selectArtpiece(this.artpiece);

  this.loadAndInitializeArtplacer();
},


beforeUnmount() {
  console.log('Before destroying component');

  this.authStore.unselectArtpiece();
  this.loadAndInitializeArtplacer = null;

},


computed: {
  authUser() {
    return this.authStore?.authUser;
  },
  userHasBid() {
    return !!this.userBid;
  },

  userBid() {
    return this.authUser?.bids?.find(
      (b) => b.artpiece_id == this.artpiece?.id
    );
  },
  userHasBought() {
    return this.authUser?.id == this.artpiece?.buyer_id;
  },
},


methods: {


  getMaxNImages(images, n) {
    if (!images) return [];
    if (images.length > n) return images.slice(0, n);
    return images;
  },
  setMainImage(image) {
    this.mainImage = image;
  },
  async addToCart() {
    try {
      this.cartStore.addToCart(this.artpiece);

      // this.isLoading = true;
      // const response = await CartService.addToCart(this.artpiece.id);
      // console.log("addToCart response", response);
      // this.isLoading = false;
      // if (!response?.success) {
      //     // TODO handle non success
      //   return;
      // }
      this.modalStore.toggle("cart", true);
    } catch (error) {
      this.isLoading = false;
      if (error?.response?.status == 404) {
        //
      }
      console.error("xx addToCart", error);
    }
  },
  async fetchArtpieceInfo() {
      try {
        this.isLoading = true;
        const response = await ArtpieceService.getArtpiece(
          this.$route?.params?.artpiece_id
        );
        this.isLoading = false;
        if (!response?.success) {
          // TODO handle non success
          return;
        }
        this.artpiece = response?.data ?? null;
        this.mainImage =
          this.artpiece &&
          this.artpiece?.images &&
          this.artpiece?.images.length != 0
            ? this.artpiece?.images[0]
            : this.defaultImage;
        this.artist = this.artpiece?.author ?? null;

      } catch (error) {
        this.isLoading = false;
        if (error?.response?.status == 404) {
          this.$router.push({
            name: "404",
            params: { notFound: this.$route?.path?.slice(1) },
          });
        }
        console.error("xx fetchArtpieceInfo", error);
      }
    },
  
  loadAndInitializeArtplacer() {
    // Load Artplacer script dynamically
    const artplacerScript = document.createElement("script");
    artplacerScript.src = "https://widget.artplacer.com/js/script.js";
    artplacerScript.onload = () => {
      // Ensure artpiece information is available before initializing Artplacer
      if (typeof ArtPlacer !== "undefined" && this.artpiece) {
        console.log("Artpiece information loaded:", this.artpiece);
        // Replace placeholder values with dynamic data
        ArtPlacer.insert({
          gallery: "78573",
          default_style: "true",
          button_width: "auto",
          unit: "cm",
          type: "3",
          text: "Voir Chez Vous !",
          title: this.artpiece.title,
          size: this.artpiece.dimensions,
          price: this.artpiece.price,
          artist: this.artpiece.author.name,
          after: "#place-the-button-after-this-element",
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Artpiece information not yet loaded");
      }
    };
    document.body.appendChild(artplacerScript);
  },

  onArtpieceBought() {
    this.fetchArtpieceInfo();
  },
  openBuyForm() {
    if (!this.authStore?.authUser) {
      this.$router.push({
        name: "login",
        query: {
          redirect: this.$route.fullName,
        },
      });
      return;
    }
    this.$router.push({
      name: "artpieces.buy",
      params: {
        username: this.artpiece?.author?.profile?.username,
        artpiece_id: this.artpiece?.id,
        artpiece_slug: this.artpiece?.slug,
      },
    });
    this.modalStore.toggle("artpieceBuyForm", true);
  },
  openBidForm() {
    if (!this.authStore?.authUser) {
      this.$router.push({
        name: "login",
        query: {
          redirect: this.$route.fullName,
        },
      });
      return;
    }
    this.$router.push({
      name: "artpieces.bid",
      params: {
        username: this.artpiece?.author?.profile?.username,
        artpiece_id: this.artpiece?.id,
        artpiece_slug: this.artpiece?.slug,
      },
    });
    this.modalStore.toggle("artpieceBidForm", true);
  },
  toggleCarouselVisible(state) {
    console.log("click event received => ", state);
    this.carouselVisible = state;
  },
},

};
</script>

I tried to set the instance to null and the expected result was that when I leave the page to another one I don't have the button that's created by the loadAndInitializeArtplacer() method

" leave the page" - in which way? Is this router page? " the instance is still there" - what kind of instance, how do you determine this? loadAndInitializeArtplacer = null doesn't make sense, loadAndInitializeArtplacer  is component method. In case  the intention is to destroy the result of ArtPlacer.insert(), this can't be done this way

no this is not the router page but the vue component, the intended result is indeed to destroy the result of artplacer.inset() , I wasn't formulating the question ideally
thanks for the insights
then how should I go about it ?

what I mean by leaving the page is that this component is responsible for a product details page, then I move to the landing page for example the result of ArtPlacer.insert(), is still there while I want it to be restricted to the product detail page

"move to the landing page" - in which way? It's unknown under which conditions the comp is unmounted, you need to make sure this happens in the first place. As for the script, always check the docs. A properly written third-party lib allows for a clean up. I see no docs for this one. Then you need to read the sources and learn how it works. In case a script is minified, use a beautifier and probably a debugger. It looks like it could be ArtPlacer.reset() here

thank you I got it now, I went through the doc and it was indeed Artplacer.rest()
